# Cleaning up CBV

Tags: python, django, methods, django-class-based-views

I've got this class which works as intended

```
class UpdateView(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, username):
        id = User.objects.get(username = username).id
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id = id)
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, user_id = id)
        form_user = UserForm(instance=user)
        form_employee = EmployeeForm(instance=employee)
        args = {'form_user': form_user,'form_employee': form_employee, 'username': username}
        return render(request, 'user/update.html', args)

    def post(self, request, username):
        id = User.objects.get(username = username).id
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id = id)
        employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, user_id = id)
        form_user = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        form_employee = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance=employee)
        if form_user.is_valid() and form_employee.is_valid():
            form_user.save()
            form_employee.save()
            return redirect('user:list')
        args = {'form_user': form_user, 'form_employee': form_employee, 'username': username}
        return render(request, 'user/update.html', args)
```

My issue is that both the get and post methods use the same id, user and employee variables. How can I clean this up?

I know I can create a render method like

```
def render(self, request, username):
    args = {'form_user': form_user, 'form_employee': form_employee, 'username': username}
    return render(request, 'user/update.html', args)
```

and then call

```
return self.render(request)
```

at the end of the get and post methods, so I don't have to define the args twice either, but currently this conflicts with the username. That's why I want to tackle the problem with the 3 variables first.

Comment: Why are you doing all this? You're not even using any of the capabilities of the TemplateView; but really you should use the existing UpdateView, which does almost all of this for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, because I'm fairly new to Django, I'd like to know what's going on, it's easier for me to understand this way. If UpdateView does all this for me, I will at some point use that, but not while I'm just starting to undestand what "all this" does.

Comment: The best resource to learn about Django CBV is : http://ccbv.co.uk/. Put this in your bookmarks, and come back to it every time you need ;)

Comment: Well, to avoid duplication is as simple as creating an extra method that you call from both your `get()` and `post()` methods: E.g. you could create a `get_object(**kwargs)` method to fetch your user based on the `kwargs` passed to your view and a `get_form()` method to return the form and a `get_context_data()` method to create the `kwargs` dictionary for the `render` method. This is exactly what `UpdateView` does. In your case you have two forms, and two objects, so maybe you want to change the methods to `get_objects()` and `get_forms()` and return dictionaries.

Comment: @Antwane, I stumbled upon that site last week and already bookmarked and used it, but with this problem I don't really know what I'm searching for.

Comment: If you do write a `def render(self, request, username)` method, then you would need to call `return self.render(request, username)`. Or, you can do `def render(self)`, access `self.request` and `self.kwargs['username']` inside the method, and call `self.render()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this view has two forms, it's not a great fit for any of the generic class based views.

A function-based view would avoid the duplicated context and would be easy to follow.

```
def update_employee(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_user = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        form_employee = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance=employee)
        if form_user.is_valid() and form_employee.is_valid():
            form_user.save()
            form_employee.save()
            return redirect('user:list')
    else:
        form_user = UserForm(instance=user)
        form_employee = EmployeeForm(instance=employee)

    args = {'form_user': form_user,'form_employee': form_employee, 'username': username}
    return render(request, 'user/update.html', args)
```

Comment: note that the first two lines are redundant, you're fetching the same `User` twice from the database. Better fetch user first (based on username) and then use it to fetch the `Employee`.

Comment: @Alasdair This wasn't my question though, as I'd like to know how to avoid the duplicate context in a CBV as I was stepping away from FBV's. What you posted is pretty much exactly what I had before I swtiched to CBV's.

Comment: You asked how to clean up the class based view, you didn't say it was essential to keep it as a class based view. Feel free to ignore this answer and stick with the class based view, but I think this answer is a useful reminder to future readers that cbvs aren't always the best choice.